# npm ERR! enoent undefined when running npm install

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-install

I used to run my Angular project in my windows 7 pc. I installed Windows 2016 and all neceserry tools. I need to install the necessary dependencies for my angular project to run since I did not backup my node_modules folder. When I run the command `npm install` I get the following error:

```
C:\Angular_Prj>npm install
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-11T09_48_53_918Z-debug.log
```

I looked for solution on google added the Windows path variable `%APPDATA%\npm` but it did not work. The strange thing is I do not use FileSaver.js in my project. How can I make `npm install` to work?

Comment: Do you have git installed and available in a terminal?

Comment: Apperently it was not available in the terminal. I had to add the path `C:\Program Files\Git` to make it work. Thank you so much. If you write an answer instead of comment I can mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: Glad to hear it was resolved. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue is caused because Git is either not installed or not available in a terminal. The give away is this line in your error log:

```
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
```

Basically this means that the command `git` could not be executed because it was not found.

Make sure git is installed and added to your PATH before running this command again.

Comment: This was the solution for me too, but I forgot to restart my IDE (WebStorm) so it didn't know about the newly installed `git` command line tool. So, remember to restart your IDE/Terminal if the problem it persists after installing git.

Answer (score 2):

I added

```
RUN apk update
RUN apk add git
```

into my dockerfile and it's now working.

Comment: This solved it for me.