# Error while executing npm install react-native-gesture-handler

Tags: windows, react-native, npm, react-navigation

After running in my project directory `npm --save install react-native-gesture-handler` or `npm install react-native-gesture-handler` my terminal shows:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/naver/hammer.js.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-03T16_55_58_791Z-debug.log
```

Can anyone help me with this? I searched online but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ERR! enoent undefined when running npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56987664/npm-err-enoent-undefined-when-running-npm-install)

Comment: Yes, just install GIT. Thank you